# Wrong CSS file being loaded

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to understand why my page is loading the wrong css file while I'm using my desktop PC.

Here's the code I have :

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css')?>" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/rh-mobile.css')?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px)" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/rh-tablet.css')?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 3000px)" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/rh.css')?>" />
```

When I check Firefox's web console, i can see that I'm getting a bunch of error messages like:

```
[11:54:09.149] Error in parsing value for 'font-weight'.  Declaration dropped. @ https://myserver/myapp/assets/css/rh-mobile.css:13

[11:54:09.150] Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. @ https://myserver/myapp/assets/css/rh-mobile.css:22

[11:54:09.150] Error in parsing value for 'background-image'. Declaration dropped. @ https://myserver/myapp/assets/css/rh-mobile.css:74

[11:54:09.150] Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. @ https://myserver/myapp/assets/css/rh-mobile.css:170
```

I wasn't expecting it to attempt to use the mobile css.  My screen resolution for my desktop is 1920 X 1200.

Can you tell me why the rh-mobile.css is being loaded / where I've gone wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Could possibly the unterminated link href tag interfere with the other links?

Comment: Not too familiar with this, but, is it based on screen resolution or the viewport?  i.e. `min-device-width` vs `min-width`?

Comment: ficuscr, i don't think so because i've tried changing it to device with but i'm still getting same results...

Comment: @dot What is your doctype?

Comment: I don't think that you can work this way. The media query goes inside the css, and not where you put it. You have to load all the css, and it will be applied according to the media queries

Comment: Joachim, <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: @dot Read the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Comment: @dot Can toy produce minimal working example of HTML and your `rh-mobile.css`? Preferably without PHP on JSFiddle? Previous comment was ment for @vals; you can use media queries in `<link>` and this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

While intuitively you might think that browsers would only download the CSS file that they need, it seems most browsers suck in all the CSS files then apply the relevant styles based on the viewport. The comments on [this page](http://www.igvita.com/2012/06/14/debunking-responsive-css-performance-myths/) give some more technical background.

Maybe it makes sense though. The alternative is that everytime you changed the window width, the browser would have to go back and check the head content and see if it should download a different CSS file.

So even though you are seeing that the rh-mobile.css stylesheet is being downloaded, from what you have posted I can't see that it's stlyes would actually be applied.

If you do actually need full control over which CSS files are being loaded, there are options like [Adapt.js](http://adapt.960.gs) or [YepNope](http://yepnopejs.com) or [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com). They are all variations on the same idea of using javascript to test for the viewpoint width before you specify details of CSS, JS or other files.

Good luck!